# How to overwrite babel's preset plugin options

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-plugin

I'm using [babel-preset-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-app) via following .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    "transform-async-generator-functions"
  ]
}
```

I need to overwrite `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` options. I tried installing plugin and adding it to .babelrc in a following way:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app"],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": false,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": false
    }],
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    "transform-async-generator-functions"
  ]
}
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any way I can do it without copy and pasting entire preset to my .babelrc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Babel doesn't currently support these sorts of overrides (see https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8799). Fortunately I found a workaround for `babel-preset-react-app`. There is an undocumented option, `useESModules`:

`['react-app', { useESModules: false }]`

Here's a config using `babel-plugin-react-app` that works for node.js:

```js
    presets: [
        ['react-app', { useESModules: false }],
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: 'commonjs',
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
```

Of course, using `babel-preset-react-app` makes the most sense if you're using `create-react-app` for your client-side bundle. If you're not using `create-react-app`, then you could consider just using [@babel/preset-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-react) directly, in which case you wouldn't need to worry about overriding the `useESModules` setting.